# How i count summary of numbers in a text file?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I did this code, but it doesnt give summary. Still I can get numbers of each row, but not summary...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace Progaram
{
    class Count
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
            {

                string[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");


                int summary = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {

                    summary += numbers[i];

                    //Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(summary);

                sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to convert string to int with `int.Parse(numbers[i])`

Comment: Given that nobody knows what's in your text file, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: And are you really *counting*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution will not compile.
You'll receive the following compilation error:

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'.

You'll want to convert the parsed string into an int.

Also, you're using a StreamReader, and reading a single line after reading in all lines.  You don't need the StreamReader in this case.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Progaram
{
    class Count
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");

            int summary = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                summary += Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(summary);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...yeah its true didint realize that still i have to convert the parsed string into int....always something missing...thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a string to an int.

You need to either convert the entire string array to an int array with

```
int[] intNumbers = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, int.Parse);
```

Then index this array instead

```
summary += intNumbers[i];
```

Or as Michael suggests, convert numbers[i] before adding

```
summary += int.Parse(numbers[i]);
```